# Integrals on symbolic regions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

Let's define a region as `r=Polygon[{{-a,0},{a,0},{a,h}}]`. I want to integrate some function over that area. Say x^2. So,  `Assuming[a>0&&h>0,Integrate[x^2,Element[{x,y},r]]]` I get `a^3h/3`, as expected.

But, what if I want to have a four-sided polygon instead? If I redefine the region as `r=Polygon[{{-a,0},{a,0},{a,h},{0,h}}]`, and then do `Assuming[a>0&&h>0,Integrate[x^2,Element[{x,y},r]]]`, it can't do the integral.

Comment: `r = Polygon[{{-a, 0}, {a, 0}, {a, h}, {0, h}}];
Area[r, Assumptions -> h > 0 && a > 0]`

Comment: This works for areas. What if I want to integrate some function over the region, like x^2? I've modified the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

r = Polygon[{{-a, 0}, {a, 0}, {a, h}, {0, h}}];
```

As pointed out by cvgmt in a comment, the area is

```
area = Assuming[a > 0 && h > 0, Area[r]]

(* (3 a h)/2 *)
```

As a workaround to do the integral, break the region `r` into three triangular regions

[image]

```
r21 = Polygon[{{-a, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, h}}];
r22 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, h}, {a, 0}}];
r23 = Polygon[{{0, h}, {a, h}, {a, 0}}];
```

The integral can be done over the subregions

```
area == Assuming[a > 0 && h > 0, 
  Total[Integrate[1, {x, y} ∈ #] & /@ {r21, r22, r23}]]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** For a more complicated integrand

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + 3) (x + y)

Assuming[a > 0 && h > 0, 
 Total[Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ #] & /@ {r21, r22, r23}] // 
  Simplify]

(* 1/60 a h (60 a + 12 a^3 + 120 h + 11 a^2 h) *)
```

**EDIT 2:** The subdivisions do not need to be only triangles; however, there are limitations. Arbitrary polygons cannot be handled. Even a [`Polygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html) representing a [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) fails.

```
r31 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, h}, {a, h}, {a, 0}}];

Assuming[a > 0 && h > 0, 
 Total[Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ #] & /@ {r21, r31}] // Simplify]
```

[image]

However, the equivalent [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) works

```
r32 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, h}];

Assuming[a > 0 && h > 0, 
 Total[Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ #] & /@ {r21, r32}] // Simplify]

(* 1/60 a h (60 a + 12 a^3 + 120 h + 11 a^2 h) *)
```

Comment: My edit yesterday specifically addressed an integral other than an area calculation.

Comment: Breaking it up works, but are we really limited only to triangular regions?

Comment: Hmm. That's a bummer.